# mysqli get_result alternative with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ware_house_indents` WHERE `has_cancel` = ? AND `eid`= ?
```

i need to get result above query in mysqli. but i cant use get_result() function because it is not working in server.i have found this below function and it is working fine.but that function not possible to pass multiple parameters.please help me to solve this problem.

```
function db_bind_array($stmt, &$row)
{
    $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $params = array();
    while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    return call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}
function db_query($db, $query, $types, $params)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $bindRet = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),
                                    array_merge(array($types), $params));
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = array();
    if (db_bind_array($stmt, $result) !== FALSE) {
        return array($stmt, $result);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return FALSE;
}
if (($qryRes = db_query($mysqli, $sql, 'i', array(&$var))) !== FALSE) {
    $stmt = $qryRes[0];
    $row = $qryRes[1];
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: this function actually allow multiple parameters

Comment: please tell me how can i pass multiple parameters using these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you a quite indirect solution.
You'd do yourself a huge favor if start using PDO instead of mysqli

It has no mysqli disadvantages when dealing with prepared statements as it has a way better implementation of above functions out of the box. So, it will let you to get your data in a few lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ware_house_indents WHERE has_cancel = ? AND eid= ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($cancel,$eid));
$data = $stm->fetchAll(); // or fetch() if you need only one row
```

that's *all*

Comment: thing is hole project has been done in mysqli.so i need to find solution in mysqli.anyway thanks to your help. appreciate lot..

Comment: you can use [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) then. It is a wrapper class written in mysqli. And it allows you multiple parameters and more safe and reliable way than these two ugly functions